# heroku local web - redirects to https://localhost, which fails

Tags: spring, heroku-cli

I'm having some trouble with getting my Spring app to deploy locally user `heroku local web`. It runs fine on a dyno.

Here's what I have in my Procfile:

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar web/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --expand-war --enable-compression --port $PORT web/target/*.war`

No mention of WebSecurityConfig nor WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter anywhere in the code.

This looks like it deploys locally fine:

```
MacBook-Pro:motherbrain brianstinar$ heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
4:40:47 PM web.1 |  Expanding gwd-web-1.4.3.war into /Users/brianstinar/Noventum/GeeksWhoDrink/motherbrain/target/tomcat.5000/webapps/expanded
4:40:47 PM web.1 |  Adding Context  for /Users/brianstinar/Noventum/GeeksWhoDrink/motherbrain/target/tomcat.5000/webapps/expanded
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-5000"]
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Starting service Tomcat
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.47
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader buildClassPath
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Unknown loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057 class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: No global web.xml found
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:40:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
4:40:48 PM web.1 |  INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
4:40:55 PM web.1 |  WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
4:40:55 PM web.1 |  WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/Users/brianstinar/Noventum/GeeksWhoDrink/motherbrain/target/tomcat.5000/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar) to constructor java.math.BigInteger(long)
4:40:55 PM web.1 |  WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
4:40:55 PM web.1 |  WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
4:40:55 PM web.1 |  WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
4:41:32 PM web.1 |  Dec 15, 2020 4:41:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
4:41:32 PM web.1 |  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-5000"]
```

BUT if I go to http://localhost:5000/ I am given a 302 to https://localhost and a Set-Cookie:
`Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E97001499B33CE33B29FB1D53A14DBFB; Path=/; HttpOnly`

I tried setting

```
server.session.cookie.secure=false
secure.cookie=false
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=false
```

inside my version.properties, and it seems like this isn't helping.

I also added:

```
    <!-- didn't work
    <server>
        <session>
            <cookie>
                <secure>false</secure>
            </cookie>
        </session>
    </server>
    -->
    <server> <!-- also didn't work -->
        <serverlet>
            <session>
                <cookie>
                    <secure>false</secure>
                </cookie>
            </session>
        </serverlet>
    </server>
```

to my web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

So, I'm not sure what is going on. I think I am not understanding how to set this directive correctly. I'm making some progress with getting this running with Tomcat, but since I inherited this project, mvn was most correct/updated for actual heroku deployment. I want to get this going locally for more rapid development, and I'd rather not deal with self signed SSL inside Tomcat for 443 and 80, but right now that's the only path I can see progressing.

I also tried running this with the Tomcat 7 maven plugin, like this:

```
mvn -X org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:run -Dtomcat.ignorePackaging=true
```

with the same error.

Now I'm progressing with setting up Tomcat 7, and actually installing an SSL certificate to run this via https:// locally, on 443. None of these conveniences in running Tomcat actually seem very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a snake oil SSL certificate, after getting Tomcat to run without any of the conveniences (no maven plugin, no heroku local plugin...) Additionally, my application was not designed to run inside a subdirectory, which majorly messed up static resource hosting being hardcoded to the web root.

So, my application has dependencies (specifically jSessionid) that require SSL, as well as other architectural decisions that reduce flexibility.